# map jump shortcut for Vim insert mode

Tags: vimrc

I wan't to map jump shortcut for insert mode such as

```
imap <A-w> <Esc>wi
imap <A-b> <Esc>bi
```

Even though `<A-b>` works perfectly. `<A-w>` appear to not work properly.

How can I map `<A-w>` for insert mode that it will jump ahead 1 word but still maintain the insert mode?

Comment: You might want to try `inoremap` and `<C-o>w` instead of `<esc>wi` (idem for `<C-o>b`).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble it works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my comment:

> You might want to try `inoremap <A-w> <C-o>w` and `inoremap <A-b> <C-o>b`

Control-o is like a oneshot normal mode: you get one “operation”, and then you’re back in insert mode. I rarely use it except in mappings, though I don’t tend to move around much in insert mode.